# Default comparison operator gives wrong result when constexpr

Tags: c++, gcc, operators, c++20, constexpr

I was testing the new feature of C++20 to automatically generate comparison operators and I found a weird case when the default operator appears to give a wrong result.

It happens only with `gcc` and only if the operator is declared as `constexpr`.

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int foo;
    constexpr bool operator==(const Foo&) const = default;
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
    constexpr bool operator==(const Bar&) const = default;
};

int main()
{
    const Foo foo0{5};
    const Foo foo1{0};
    std::cout << "Foo: {" << foo0.foo << "} == {" << foo1.foo << "} => " << ((foo0 == foo1) ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;

    const Bar bar0{5};
    const Bar bar1{0};
    std::cout << "Bar: {" << bar0.foo << "} == {" << bar1.foo << "} => " << ((bar0 == bar1) ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

when compiled with `gcc` gives:

```
Foo: {5} == {0} => false
Bar: {5} == {0} => true
```

but when compiled with `clang` gives:

```
Foo: {5} == {0} => false
Bar: {5} == {0} => false
```

Compiler Explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/vbzo35an5

I'm assuming it's a bug in `gcc` but I don't know all the quirks of the language so I've decided to ask here before reporting it.

Comment: The gcc repo trunk version is massively buggy like trunk version of every meaningful product. Most people (besides developers of gcc) are not using it so it is unlikely to get answer why that particular input gives so odd output.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I don't really need to know why. I'm just making sure that it is in fact an error and not some weird corner case described in the standard, like e.g. that logical operators don't short-circuit if overloaded.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I'm targeted GCC in my question because it is the one that behaves differently than I would expect and because this is the compiler I'm using. I don't exclude the possibility that Clang is wrong.

Comment: Then my advice is to stop using versions of any products that are anticipated to be buggy. It does not matter how quickly, efficiently and/or in how modern way you get wrong answers from such software.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I don't know what your problem is. The behavior of GCC is exactly the same on a stable release 11.1.

Comment: And the whole gcc 11 is several times reported to be buggy in stackoverflow and everywhere else. It is not my problem that I don't use it.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: "*And the whole gcc 11 is several times reported to be buggy in stackoverflow and everywhere else.*" That's irrelevant. Once you're not talking about trunk, once you're dealing with an actual released version, your initial point (that trunk is expected to be buggy so you shouldn't test code on it) becomes irrelevant. And accusing someone of acting in bad faith because they're talking about a problem that exists in a *release* version is pretty out there.

Comment: @NicolBolas you are correct, but OP was reporting issue with trunk. I did not know that 11 is buggy as I don't have time to use versions newer than 2 years. It made me to search for defect reports only after he said that released version is defective as well in comments.

Comment: Submitted [100835](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100835). On the plus side, the addition of the `constexpr` keyword is totally unnecessary here (the defaulted comparison is implicitly `constexpr` anyway), so the easy fix for your bug is to just... not provide the keyword.

Comment: @ÖöTiib You don't have time to click on a dropdown menu in the compiler explorer link, but you have time to write multiple comments disparaging the state of gcc? Maybe rethink your priorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the code as written ought to work, so this is a GCC bug. The default `operator==` is expected to do an equality comparison of all the subobjects, not just the member subobjects.

You can see from [the assembly output](https://godbolt.org/z/qvW1rGM64) that GCC 11.1 produces the same comparison operator code for `Bar` as it would for a struct with no subobjects.

Comment: I would report it on Bugzilla but I see @Barry did this already. Thanks!